# How to expose security flaws in my website

Tags: security, web

Is there any service, or test suite or something which I can run against my site and expose any major security flaws. I don't expect I'll need to worry about hackers, but I want to eliminate security risks which can easily be exploited. i.e. SQL injection, cross site scripting etc..

Comment: SQL injection and XSS are often at least a little site-specific; I doubt you'll find an automated test suite that will test those meaningfully. It could test for known bugs in standard components, but you can prevent those just by keeping said components up to date.

Comment: I understand Anonymous provides really good service, but I'm not really sure you would want to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) to detect XSS/SQLi vulnerabilities. It can be pretty hard on servers (brute forcing stuff, generating lots of requests), so you may want to read about its options/flags.

For SQL injection, [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/) is pretty good in finding and exploiting SQL injections. Definitely worth a try.

I regularly use both of these tools for my penetration tests and they are pretty good at finding meaningful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for sql injection testing, it's the one i prefer

Havij v1.15 Advanced SQL Injection

http://www.itsecteam.com/en/projects/project1.htm

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ASafaWeb analyzer for ASP.NET web sites](http://asafaweb.com/). (If ASP.NET is applicable to you... )

It doesn't do SQL Injection attacks, but nevertheless useful.
It's written by Troy Hunt, and make sure you listen to the [Dotnetrocks.com episode 735](http://dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=735) where he was interviewed.